# Los registros en una tabla de la base de datos phpmyadmin mysql me quedan registrados con caracteres erróneos

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien quiero pedirles el favor con lo siguiente:

Tengo un campo de tipo varchar(255), dicho campo dentro de la base de datos tiene registros bien almacenados y el cotejamiento inicial de dicho campo era utf8_unicode_ci y  los datos aparecían bien registrados.
Pero desafortunadamente “alguien” del equipo de desarrollo accidentalmente lo cambio por utf8mb4_unicode_ci  y todos los datos aparecen registrados de manera errónea así por ejemplo:

El???????????.

O así:

P???????????..

Al volver a establecer el cotejamiento del campo a utf8_unicode_ci, me siguen mostrando los registros de manera errónea.

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Comment: ¿Aparecen así en la tabla directamente o hablamos de algún código en algún lenguaje de programación con el cual estás obteniendo los datos?

Comment: Si hicieron eso con el phpmyadmin, al lado del cotejamiento hay una casilla que pone "Cambiar todas las colaciones de columna" que diria que fuerza el cambio de esos caracteres al nuevo cotejamiento (no se como lo hace, supongo que los convertirá usando alguna función de PHP sabiendo el cotejamiento anterior y el final).  Si hicieron eso pues ahi tienes el problema, o si lo has hecho tu al revertirlo y ellos no entonces tambien. No se, lo digo como pista, pero es probable que ya tengais todos esos datos corruptos y debais arreglarlo a pelo exportandolos a archivo y editando el sql.

Comment: A.Cedano, aparece así en la base de datos